# List and Iterator after and before sorting behavior

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am going through STL in cpp and I found List.

Wrote below code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> ls;
    ls.push_back(23);
    ls.push_front(34);
    ls.push_front(39);
    ls.push_front(334);
    ls.push_front(434);
    ls.push_front(7834);
    ls.push_front(634);
    ls.push_front(934);

    list<int>::iterator it10 = ls.begin();
    list<int>::iterator it11 = ls.end();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator it12 = ls.rbegin();
    list<int>::reverse_iterator it13 = ls.rend();

    ls.sort();

    for (auto it = it10; it != it11; it++)
    {
        cout << *(it) << "\n";
    }
}
```

So here I am defining iterators before sorting the list and I get Output as :

```
934
7834
```

But if I sort the before defining the Iterators like:

```
ls.sort();

list<int>::iterator it10 = ls.begin();
list<int>::iterator it11 = ls.end();
list<int>::reverse_iterator it12 = ls.rbegin();
list<int>::reverse_iterator it13 = ls.rend();
```

I am getting correct output :

```
23
34
39
334
434
634
934
7834
```

Why is it behaving like this how does this work? please explain.
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect that the _start_ and the _end_ pointer of a linked list stay the same after sorting the linked list? If you're looking for an _in place_ sort, use a `std::vector<int>`, the `begin()` and `end()` iterators will stay the same even after sorting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you please explain why my first output only printing 2 numbers?  I just don't get it.

Comment: `ls.sort();` changes the values of `begin()` and `end()`, they aren't the same as you saved before., you're outputting only the range of sorted numbers between these two. That's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it10` is an iterator to the element `934` in the list. `it11` is an iterator to the end of the list. After sorting `it10` is an iterator to the element `934` and `it11` is an iterator to the end of the list. The elements starting from `934` after sorting are:

```
943 
7834
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) about `std::list::sort`:

> std::sort requires random access iterators and so cannot be used with
> list . This function also differs from std::sort in that it does not
> require the element type of the list to be swappable, preserves the
> values of all iterators, and performs a stable sort.

With `std::sort` iterators get invalidated. Thats not the case with `std::list::sort`. Sloppy speaking, iterators into `std::list`s are more stable than others generally. In your example `it10` and `it11` still point to the same elements. After sorting, the element that was at the first position is no longer at the first position. It is at the second but last position and `it11` still points to the lists `end`.

Consider that a `std::list` is a linked list, to change order it isnt necessary to modify or move elements to other postion in memory, only links have to be updated.

Comment: After sort values : ```23,34,39,334,434,634,934,7834``` and ```begin``` and ```end``` are ```23, 0``` now  the for loop looks like ```for(auto it =  23 ; it!= 0; i++ )``` then why are ```934 and 7834``` are printing as output? i am sorry to bother but unable to grasp it thanks for the help

Comment: @heeat because you hold iterators to `934` and to the end of the list. After sorting the two iterator still point to `934` and the end of the list

Comment: @heeat what else did you expect and why? I can only reiterate what I already said: After sorting the iterators still refer to the same elements in the list.

Comment: Got it ! Sorry I was missing the obvious , confused because I was debugging ```cout << *ls.begin()``` and ```cout << *ls.end()``` after sorting instead of ```cout <<  it10``` and ```cout << it11``` which I was using in the ```for loop```. if I use ```begin``` and ```end``` instead of ```it10``` and ```it11``` inside the ```for loop``` I will get a different result right? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @heeat if you print elements from `begin` till `end` then you will see all of them, yes

Comment: @heeat `it10 = ls.begin()` does not mean that `it10` will forever point to the begin of the list.

Comment: Understood, I tried and it is working correctly now. Thanks for the help!